# Apache Spark: Unpersisting RDD after next action?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

In spark programming, when I call persist/cache() on an RDD, I found that its lifespan for reusability is not optimal in many cases:

Namely, it always last for a few hours, after which an RDD storage is evicted from executor's memory and disk. This sometimes cause performance/GC problems: sometimes an RDD storage drains memory long after the RDD implementation itself on driver has been garbage collected (until a few hours later, but for a job that cache/checkpoint often this is still inefficient). Sometimes vice versa: an RDD storage get evicted even the RDD object is still referenced by the driver jvm, and it may be reused later.

I'm looking for a way to override it. The "unpersist()" function is rarely useful: due to lazy execution it can only be called after next action, which can't be determined by the time it is created. Is there a pattern to  mark an RDD as "unpersist after next action"? This can save a lot of memory and disk space.